# Slide images instead of fading in

Tags: jquery

I've made a simple image gallery where the images fadeIn as the thumb image clicked.
What I am trying to change is as the thumb image clicked the requested gallery image doesn't fadeIn but slides to the left/right.

http://jsfiddle.net/TfEn4/

```
$('.fotos').not(':first').hide();
$('.info').not(':first').hide();

$('.gal-links ul li a').click(function() {
    var activeLink = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.info').hide();
    $('.gal-links ul li a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.fotos').hide();
    $(activeLink).fadeIn('slow');
    $('.info').fadeIn('slow');
    return false;
});
```

How should I change my code for this? Animate and positioning is the right way?

Comment: Images are missing in the fiddle, please add the image folder path(absolute) in the external resources section

Comment: Use Jquery UI's [slide effect](http://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/?rdfrom=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.jquery.com%2Fmw%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DUI%2FEffects%2FSlide%26redirect%3Dno) or animate() method for width property

Comment: Stop (Mis)Using Return False http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TfEn4/3/ - Using Jquery UI and added a kitten picture!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Jquery UI's [slide effect](http://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=UI/Effects/Slide&redirect=no) or use animate() method for width property

```
$(activeLink).toggle( "slide" );
```

Here is a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TfEn4/5/) for slide effect.

For using animate method you can do like this

```
$(activeLink).show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
```

and for hiding

```
$(activeLink).hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
```

Comment: I like the kitten better than the JQuery logo! ;)

Comment: Haha. Me too actually. I am too lazy to search for a better image